# php loop array multidimensional

Tags: php

I have an array which keeps on getting bigger and dynamic. For example it looks like:-

```
array(0 => 'transactions' =>array(0 => array('paymentid' => abcd, 'amount' =>-3), 1 => array('paymentid' => ab, 'amount' => 4)) 1 =>'transactions' =>array(0 => array('paymentid' => ab, 'amount' =>-3), 1 => array('paymentid' => ab, 'amount' => 4))
```

Now how do I loop through them so to get amount where Payment Id is ab and amount is positive. I want to get them in this form:-

```
array(0 => array('amount' => 4), 1 => array('amount' => 4))
```

I tried few methods but I couldnt loop more than 0 :(

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid array. Is there supposed to be another key after `'transactions'`? You can't have `a => b => c` in an array, it has to be `a => b, c => d`

Comment: Could you show the output of `var_dump($array)`, with all the formatting so we can see the nesting of the array?

Comment: And how might your array data vary?  Might you have have two positive values in the same transaction? How does this affect your desired output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Your array
$arrTransction =array( array('transactions' =>  array( array('paymentid' => 'abcd', 'amount' => -3), array('paymentid' => 'ab', 'amount' => 4)) ),
       array( 'transactions' =>  array( array('paymentid' => 'ab', 'amount' =>-3), array('paymentid' => 'ab', 'amount' => 4)) ));

Loops in
foreach($arrTransction as $key => $val){
    foreach($val['transactions'] as $k => $v){
        if($v['paymentid'] == 'ab' &&  $v['amount'] >= 0){
            $amount[] = array('amount' => $v['amount']);
        }

    }
}
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [amount] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [amount] => 4 ) )
```